# PHP Passing function as a parameter syntax

Tags: php, function, syntax

can someone pls fill me in on the correct syntax for this in PHP? I have:

```
function mainFunction($str,$thingToDoInMain){
   $thingToDoInMain($str);
}

function printStr($str){
    echo $str;
}

mainFunction("Hello",printStr);
```

I am running this on WAMP and I get an error/warning saying

> use of undefined constant printStr - assumed 'printStr' on line 5

...and then I get "Hello" printed out as desired further down the page.

So, how do a refer to the function `printStr` in the last line to get rid of warning? I have tried `$printStr`, `printStr()` and `$printStr`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way in the world that this code can print `Hello` as it is, unless you made a typo. `thingToDoInMain` is not a valid function name. The value of that variable, `$thingToDoInMain`, is

Comment: Yeah. I made a typo. Have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, function names are passed as strings.

```
mainFunction("Hello", "printStr");
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a `$` sign before your `thingToDoInMain`  function call making it a proper function name, because `thingToDoInMain` itself is not a function name. Whereas the value contained in `$thingToDoInMain` is a function name.

```
<?php
function mainFunction($str,$thingToDoInMain){
     $thingToDoInMain($str);   //Here $ is missing
}

function printStr($str){
    echo $str;
}

mainFunction("Hello","printStr");   // And these quotes
?>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/IImavRBM)